# what is the big O notation for this pseudo-script

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, computer-science

I am studying big-O notation and I want to find the big O notation of a Math problem I solved from Project Euler.

```
total

for x (0..9){
    for y (0..9){
        for z(0..9){
            if(some_condition == true){
                total = total + permute(x,y,z)
            }
        }
    } }
print total
```

my guess is O(N^3) because of the 3 loops but I am not sure

Comment: Since the loops are till constant values, to me the complexity seems to be complexity of the permute function.

Comment: O(1).  There's no variable input.

Comment: Should `for x (0...9)` be `for x (0...N)`?

Answer (score 2):

The complexity is = `O(10*10*10*C(permute))` = `O(1000*C(permute))` = `O(k*C(permute))`,
where `C(permute)` is the complexity of the function `compute(x,y,z)`.

Comment: 0...9 is 10 iterations.

Comment: @thang Changed it. Although, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: It was off by about 27%!  Is that not much?

Comment: What I meant was that the complexity is still `O(k*C(permute))`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comment by [@thang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779316/thang), the complexity of the algorithm is actually `O(1)`.

One important point when we talk about the time complexity of an algorithm is that:

> We always consider the time that the algorithm requires **with respect to the size of it's input**.

Note that although we are invoking the `permute()` function `10 * 10 * 10 = 1000` times (for `x, y, z = 0, 1, ..., 9`), the running time of each invocation of `permute()` is upper-bounded by:

```
T := max { T(0, 0, 0), T(0, 0, 1), ..., T(0, 0, 9),
           T(0, 1, 0), T(0, 1, 1), ..., T(0, 1, 9),
           ...
           T(9, 9, 0), T(9, 9, 1), ..., T(9, 9, 9) }
```

i.e. It is upper-bounded by the maximum running time on the 1000 possible input values.

So in the worst case, the running time of your algorithm is upper-bounded by `1000 * T`. Observe that `T` is actually **independent** of the input size (because you have no input whatsoever), so the running time of your algorithm is actually `O(1)`.

Comment: This answer is better than mine, and is accurate enough to be accepted.